# Ignore space when converting String

Tags: java, string

I've created a method which converts a String into ****'s as I am creating a Hangman game, and I was wondering how I ensure that the space is just a space rather than a *. Below is an extract from my code:

```
secretPirateWord="ahoy there"

public void secretWordAsStars(){
for (int i= 0; i < secretPirateWord.length(); i++){
System.out.print("");
pirateWord = secretPirateWord.toCharArray()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Arrays.fill()`. I surmise here that your `char[]` will be of fixed length anyway, so, for one `char` array `array` you can:

```
Arrays.fill(array, '*');
```

And then pick individual characters to fill in the array and make a `String` out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just `replaceAll` "not space" with "*":

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String secretPirateWord="ahoy there";
    System.out.println(secretPirateWord.replaceAll("\\S", "*"));
}
```

Output:

```
**** *****
```